# selecting integer intervals with specific intra-inter length from random integer intervals

Tags: r

Here, I have a one-dimensional integer space (consist of random intervals defined by their begin and end). I would like to select consequent integer intervals with specific intra-inter length.

An integer interval means a set of consecutive increasing integers, defined by a begin integer and an end integer. Some intervals in the initial set are totally included in others or partially overlapped with others.

I describe my question using the following dummy.

(1) the data (integer space with integer intervals defined by their begin and end) I have,

```
integer.space <- data.frame(
                     begin=c(1,5,6,15,31,51,102), 
                     end  =c(7,9,13,21,49,52,108)
                 )
```

(2) what I want is to select the consequent integer intervals with intra-length of 3 and inter-length of 2. and output the selected intervals as begin and end. In this selection, I would like to select more integer intervals as most as it could be.

```
begin, end\n
1,3\n
6,8\n
11,13\n
16,18\n
31,33\n
36,38\n
41,43\n
46,48\n
102,104\n
```

Comment: It is unclear to me what you exactly mean by intra en inter length.

Comment: my intention is to select integers from a specific integer space. The selection should obey several rule: (1) the selected integers would occurred as intervals (consequent integers); (2) the length of the selected integers is the intra-length, which would be 3. (3) the distance between two adjacent selected intervals is inter-length, which would be 2. (4) I want the integer selected be presented as intervals.

Comment: Thanks so much to your reply, Dear Paul.

Comment: By consequent you mean consecutive?

Comment: yes, it is. Thanks a lot for your kindness.

Comment: I edited your question, if it is accepted by moderators the changes should appear soon.

Comment: Is your initial set of intervals free of overlap (like it is in your example)?

Comment: In your example, you don't have any intra-lengths of exactly 3.

Comment: Dear Richie and DWin, Thanks for your kind responses.

Comment: Dear Nick. The relationship of the intervals in the initial set are complex, some of them were totally included in others, some were partially overlapped with others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this in several steps:

1) Reduce the integer.space to nonoverlapping intervals.

2) Create a collection of intervals, and shift them so that they start at start points of the disjoint pieces of the integer space:

```
intra <- 3
inter <- 2
intervals <- data.frame(begin=seq(from=min(integer.space$begin),to=max(integer.space$end),by=intra+inter))
intervals$end <- intervals$begin + inter
for (k in 2:nrow(integer.space)) {
  # overlaps the start of this component?
  shift <- (intervals$begin>integer.space$end[k-1]) & (intervals$begin<integer.space$begin[k]) 
  if (any(shift)) {
    shift.ind <- min(which(shift))
    intervals[shift.ind:nrow(intervals),] <- intervals[shift.ind:nrow(intervals),] + integer.space$begin[k] - intervals$begin[shift.ind]
  }
}
```

3) Remove those that lie outside the integer space

```
goodbegins <- sapply(intervals$begin, function (x) { 
    any( (x>=integer.space$begin) & (x<=integer.space$end) )
  } )
goodends <- sapply(intervals$end, function (x) { 
    any( (x>=integer.space$begin) & (x<=integer.space$end) )
  } )
intervals <- intervals[goodbegins&goodends,]

intervals
```

Comment: Dear petrelharp, thanks a lot. you present an attractive solution. I am now thinking if it is the best one. I am wondering if it can select more integer intervals as most as it could be.

Comment: I intend to receive this solution as the answer, I think it exactly solved my problem. Thanks a lot, petrelharp.

Answer (score 1):

Partial steps: I think you first want to define the continuous sequences. The one condition you did not put in your test case was a completely overlapped sequence.

```
> ints2 <- ints2[c(1:3,3,4:7),]
> ints2[4,] <- c(8,10)

require(IRanges) # from BioConductor repository
x <- IRanges(start = ints2$begin, width=1+ints2$end-ints2$begin)
asNormalIRanges(x)
#--------------
NormalIRanges of length 5
    start end width
[1]     1  13    13
[2]    15  21     7
[3]    31  49    19
[4]    51  52     2
[5]   102 108     7
```

Further progress: To generate the sequence of 2,3,2,3,2,3... within overlapping ranges you can use:

```
# c(start, cumsum( rep(c(2,3), 1+(end-start)%/%5)
```

But then you need to trim the sequence when it "overshoots the "end":

```
seqcand <- c(cumsum(c(31, rep(c(2,3), 1+(49-31)%/%5))), 49)
seqcand[ 1: (min(which(seqcand > 49, arr.ind=TRUE))-1)]
# [1] 31 33 36 38 41 43 46 48
```

Comment: Thanks, Dear DWin. I am still struggling with this problem.

Comment: Dear DWin, Thanks for your updating and good point of IRanges package.